# The tools of inline editor is not showing for modal and textarea

Tags: jquery, .net, modal-dialog, asp.net-mvc-partialview, inline-editor

I wrote this code to integrate the editor:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/18.0.0/inline/ckeditor.js"></script>

<div class="col-sm-12" id="modalD">

</div>

<script>
     InlineEditor
            .create(document.querySelector('#modalD'))
  
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            } );
</script>
```

Does anyone have a suggestion as to how to integrate the `ckeditor` for modal?

Comment: Inside `document.ready`  try:  `CKEDITOR.replace(‘#modalD’); `

Answer (score 0):

Baloon and Inline CKEditor doesn't work for textarea.for more clearance you can go through the documentation of CKEditor.